# Select data base on Max value on another table

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have 3 tables
[image]

And I would like to get the result which show the name of persons who have the most years of experience. The result look like:

[image]

How can I modify my code to get that result by using the `Max()` instead of `YearsOfExperience == 4`?

```
  from es in EmployeeSkills
  where es.YearsOfExperience == 4 
  select new
 {

Name = Employees
        .Where(emp => emp.EmployeeID == es.SkillID)
        .Select(emp => new 
        {
            Name = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName                 
        })

  }
```

Comment: do a `Linq How to perform Max google search or use > 4`

Comment: You need to order by descending and take first 4

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FirstOrDefault](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx) instead:

```
  var result = (from es in EmployeeSkills
  select new
 {
         YearsOfExperience = es.YearsOfExperience,
         Name = Employees
        .Where(emp => emp.EmployeeID == es.SkillID)
        .Select(emp => new 
        {
            Name = emp.FirstName + " " + emp.LastName                 
        })

  }).ToList().OrderByDesc(es => es.YearsOfExperience).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Can we do that with Max()?

Answer (score 0):

This works...  Try this in LinqPad

```
void Main()
{
    var result = EmployeeSkills
        .GroupBy(x => x.YearsOfExperience)
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Key)
        .Take(1)
        .SelectMany(x => x)
        .Select(x => Employees
                .Where(y => y.EmployeeID == x.EmployeeID)
                .Select(y => y.FirstName + " " + y.LastName).Single()
        );

    result.Dump();
}

public class Employee 
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

public class Skill 
{
    public int SkillID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool RequiresTicket { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeSkill 
{
    public int EmployeeSkillID { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public int SkillID { get; set;}
    public int Level {get; set;}
    public int YearsOfExperience {get; set;}
}

public List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee> {
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 1, FirstName = "Wallace",  LastName = "Daniels" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 2, FirstName = "Monique",  LastName = "Flowers" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 3, FirstName = "Woodrow",  LastName = "Gross" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 4, FirstName = "Ed",       LastName = "Barton" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 5, FirstName = "Marjorie", LastName = "Smith" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 6, FirstName = "Dora",     LastName = "Yates" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 7, FirstName = "Sylvia",   LastName = "Bush" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 8, FirstName = "Florence", LastName = "Webster" },
    new Employee { EmployeeID = 9, FirstName = "New",      LastName = "Guy" }   
};

public List<Skill> Skills = new List<Skill>() {
    new Skill { SkillID = 1, Description = "Working", RequiresTicket = false }
};

public List<EmployeeSkill> EmployeeSkills = new List<EmployeeSkill>() {
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 1,  EmployeeID = 1, SkillID = 1, Level = 3, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 2,  EmployeeID = 2, SkillID = 1, Level = 1, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 3,  EmployeeID = 3, SkillID = 1, Level = 3, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 4,  EmployeeID = 4, SkillID = 1, Level = 1, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 5,  EmployeeID = 5, SkillID = 1, Level = 2, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 6,  EmployeeID = 6, SkillID = 1, Level = 1, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 7,  EmployeeID = 7, SkillID = 1, Level = 3, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 8,  EmployeeID = 8, SkillID = 1, Level = 1, YearsOfExperience = 8 },
    new EmployeeSkill { EmployeeSkillID = 9, EmployeeID = 9, SkillID = 1, Level = 1, YearsOfExperience = 1 },
};
```

Comment: I tried these statement on LinqPad 4 and got this error:
System.Linq.IGrouping<int?,LINQPad.User.EmployeeSkills>' does not contain a definition for 'Employees' and no extension method 'Employees' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IGrouping<int?,LINQPad.User.EmployeeSkills>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways you could do this. Here's one of the few:

```
 int maxYears = (from s in EmployeeSkills
 select s.YearsOfExperience).Max();

 var query = (from s in EmployeeSkills
 where s.YearsOfExperience == maxYears
 select s).SingleOrDefault();
```

Another way:

```
var query = EmployeeSkills
         .SingleOrDefault(e => e.YearsOfExperience
                     .Equals(EmployeeSkills.Max(y => y.YearsOfExperience)));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there anyway to do the select FirstName + LastName where YearsOfExperience.Max() in 1 statement?

Comment: I'm not at a computer right now, but my second query, you can project just like you did in your question